# Android how to adjust image background to be centered

Tags: android

I have `ToggleButton`with an image setted in `android:background` property. This background image fits all the background.

I would like to center a smaller background image inside a large ToggleButton avoiding to enlarge the image to fit all the background.

Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it:

First, we create our ToggleButton in our XML layout. Think our drawable is a selector which contains two (for selected and unselected states) images smaller than the background of the `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton
     android:id="@+id/messageSeeMoreToggleButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textOff=""
     android:textOn=""
     android:background="@drawable/selector_wall_toggle_see_more_button"
     android:contentDescription="@string/conversation_see_more_Button_description" />
```

Then, in our class `Activity`, we find our `ToggleButton` as usual:

```
viewHolder.messageSeeMoreToggleButton = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.messageSeeMoreToggleButton);
```

Now, we are going to change the appearance of the drawable, using `StateListDrawable.setLevel`. We can adjust the value in `setLevel` for better result:

```
StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = (StateListDrawable) viewHolder.messageSeeMoreToggleButton.getBackground();
stateListDrawable.setLevel(3000);
```

So, we will have our image centered inside the `ToggleButton` background, avoiding to enlarge the image.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lay text on top of an image, you're probably going to have to set the image in code instead of XML.  Something like:

```
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable myimage = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage);
Button mybutton = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
myimage.setBounds(0, 0, myimage.getIntrinsicWidth(), myimage.getIntrinsicHeight());
mybutton.setCompoundDrawables(myimage, null, null, null);
```